# Immutable attribute or Immutable wrapper object - which one?

Tags: orleans

Quick question for those that might know!

It appears there are two ways to mark a message as immutable in Orleans..

new Immutable(...)  or with an attribute [Immutable] on the message class

Which is preferred and more importantly why - or is it just a matter of personal taste?

Comment: smells like a declarative vs imperative programming question to me -> 1 vote for declarative in this case.

Comment: I strongly suspect that Immutable attribute is discovered via reflection and at the end it will be new Immutable(...). So I agree with BozoJoe that it's a personal taste for readability and maybe a little sliver of performance difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Immutable] applies to all instances of that class (everywhere you use it, the instances of this class will be considered as Immutable), while new Immutable(...)  applies to every instance usage (at one place you can pass your class as mutable and at other place as Immutable). If all instances of this class will be always Immutable, [Immutable] is a more terse and elegant approach.

Comment: Yup I agree :) I've gone down the path of using [Immutable] where my code base owns the source code and while using the wrapper where code is not under my control!